# Match each sublist item with every item in every other sublist (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, multidimensional-array, python-itertools

I have a list of lists of boards, `boards`. `boards` contains a number of sublists that each have the same type of board in them. Essentially: `[[...], [...], ...]`.

Say the first sublist was 1 and the second sublist was 2. I need to compare the each element of 1 to each element of 2. So, I need the pairs `(1[0], 2[0]), (1[0], 2[1])...(1[0], 2[len(2)-1]);(1[0], 2[0])...`.

The problem is, I don’t know how many sublists are in `boards`, meaning I can’t just do n `for` loops. This is what I have right now:

```
for sublist in boards:
    for board in sublist:
        for board_indices in itertools.permutations(range(len(sublist)), len(boards)):
            matched_boards = [boards[a][j] for a, j in enumerate(i)]
```

But I think I’m overthinking it. I am sure there is an easier, simpler, more readable way to do this but I’m not sure what it is.

Comment: You question is a bit unclear. Do you want to generate every pair of items from every pair of sublists in `boards`?

Comment: Also, the code you posted is a bit odd. Your `for board_indices` loop does nothing with the generated permutations in `board_indices`, and you have a variable `i` that isn't defined.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, that's correct. Also, sorry about the `i` variable, I was trying to make my code more readable and forgot to replace the `i` with `board_indices`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only pairs you want, you could combine `itertools.combinations` with `itertools.product` to give every possible cross-sublist pair:

```
for sublist_pair in itertools.combinations(nested_iter, 2):
    for item_pair in itertools.product(*sublist_pair):
        print(item_pair)
```

Giving:

```
(1, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(1, 'c')
(2, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'a')
(3, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(1, 0.1)
(1, 0.2)
(1, 0.3)
(2, 0.1)
(2, 0.2)
(2, 0.3)
(3, 0.1)
(3, 0.2)
(3, 0.3)
('a', 0.1)
('a', 0.2)
('a', 0.3)
('b', 0.1)
('b', 0.2)
('b', 0.3)
('c', 0.1)
('c', 0.2)
('c', 0.3)
```

Comment: I _suspect_ that your second solution is what the OP wants, but I guess we'll just have to wait and see. :)